# Pass a secret to a program started over SSH

Tags: python, linux

I'm starting a Python program over SSH and I would like to pass a secret to it.

```
ssh remote python program.py
```

I control the code of the program so I can implement any method that I would like to. I've considered the following options:

**Use a command-line argument**

```
ssh remote python program.py --secret=abc
```

This won't work since any user on the local and remote machine can see that SSH and the program were invoked with this parameter.

**Use TCP**

```
ssh -L 1234:localhost:1234 remote python progam.py
```

The program would listen on port 1234 and wait for me to send the secret over a connection. This also doesn't work since any program could connect to port 1234 and pass garbage secrets to `program.py`.

**Use stdin**

```
cat secret.txt | ssh remote python program.py
```

This would work, but unfortunately for my use case stdin is already used to pass other data to the program.

Do I have any other options? Is stdin the only way?

Comment: Copy `secret.txt` to the target machine using `scp` before starting the program.

Comment: @JohnGordon Where do I copy it so that only said program can read it?

Comment: You can use an environment variable `FOO=bar shh...` but that would expose the secret.

Comment: You can add the secret to a file and sign it and send it to remote, with public key present on remote you can verify that the secret wasn't tempered, but this will not hide the secret, just ensure its origin

Comment: Where you copy doesn't really matter what you really need to care is what permission you should give to the file. The file must have read permission for only the user running the process

Comment: Supposing I understand right, your question is about using a specific file descriptor.  If so, you could improve your question in this way.

Answer (score 0):

> Is stdin the only way?

Provided you cannot use a socket (TCP or UDP) to transmit the secret information to `remote`; it seems `stdin` is the only way, considering the constraints you mention and the way you describe your problem.

A socket would give you a file descriptor interface upon which you can write the local file to the remote end.  As you cannot use it, `stdin` lasts as a practical option for a message-based application protocol.  See below.

> Do I have any other options?

Yes, you have many other options.  i.e., you can create a message-based protocol by creating objects and doing `read`/`write` from inside `program.py`.

```py
class Message:
     SECRET, INFO = range(2) # see also: from enum import auto, Enum
         #https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/enum.html

     def __init__(self, type_, content_):
         self.type = type_
         self.content = content_


msec = Message(Message.SECRET, "secret here")
minf = Message(Message.INFO, "clear info here")
```

Comment: This doesn't work since the file descriptor won't exist on the remote end.

Comment: @Overv you right.  Please see my second suggestion, a message-based application protocol.  I will edit my answer and remove the part I mention file descriptors.